# What is this stuffed pastry called in English?

Tags: word-request, nouns

I'm currently making these:

[image: Paszteciki]

It's a puff pastry stuffed with meat, mushrooms and spices, a roll cut into such small pieces. I wanted to brag about these on a forum except I realized I have no clue what they are called in English.

Comment: What are they called in your language?

Comment: @user3169: "Paszteciki" which in direct translation means "Little pâtés". Google Translate is being unhelpful, translating them as "pies".

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_rn=4&gs_ri=psy-ab&cp=18&gs_id=b&xhr=t&q=paszteciki+pasties&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=paszteciki+pasties&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.Yms&fp=ce5d43a4985ebd88&biw=1280&bih=789) suggests that "paszteciki" are a kind of "pasties".

Comment: @Stephen: It's quite possible it's the right word. There are "closed" variants of these too.

Comment: 'Pastry' would probably be better; *pâté* in English generally means the 'paste' made from liver. I'd use the native term - that's pretty common in cuisine. Or you might post this question on [cooking.SE] and see if anybody there has a better name. In any case, it looks worth boasting about.

Comment: @Stephen: It seems that's the correct answer and if you post it, I'll accept. They appear in many variants, as half-circles a'la calzone, square pyramids, triangles like pierogi, the form of rolls is one of many, probably most common in Poland because it's the least work and baked stuffing on the sides adds to the taste, but by no means ultimate. I believe there's a common etymology too.

Comment: @StoneyB: The polish counterpart of the word pâté, "pasztet" covers a range of products that combine pastry and meat, starting with paste like the one you mention, through various forms, to baked goods with meat content (not as stuffing but mixed with the dough). The diminutive form "pasztecik" is reserved for dough stuffed with various salty/spicy stuffing (with exception of sauerkraut, which get a separate name.) I'm well aware this is very far from English use of pâté thus the question...

Comment: @Stephen I thought *pasty* was reserved for the larger handheld pies from Cornwall; but a little Googling found several recipes for paszteciki titled Mushroom pasties or Polish pasties or whatever. Go for it.

Comment: Those are similar to vol-au-vent ([1](http://www.wordnik.com/words/vol-au-vent), [2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vol-au-vent), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vol-au-vent)),  “A light pastry shell filled with a ragout of meat or fish” or  “a small canapé - circular pieces of puff pastry with a small hole which accommodates various fillings, such as mushrooms, prawns, fruit, cheese, etc” but for vol-au-vent the hole is vertical (not horizontal) and is closed at the bottom.

Comment: Stephen and SF., that is a misuse of the word *pasties*. See the answer of Mari-Lou A and the comments under it, to find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would describe the OP's dish as being neither pasties nor patties.

The most well known type of pasties in the UK are called [***Cornish pasty***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasty)

Wikipedia defines a Cornish pasty as being:

> ... shaped like a ‘D’ and crimped on one side,
>   not on the top. Its ingredients should include uncooked beef, swede
>   (called turnip in Cornwall), potato and onion, with a light
>   seasoning of salt and pepper, keeping a chunky texture. The pastry
>   should be golden and retain its shape when cooked and cooled

[image: Cornish Pasty]

I believe the dish cooked by the OP does not resemble a pasty in the slightest.

Patties don't quite work for me either. There is a popular dish in Jamaica called, interestingly enough,  [**Jamaican patty**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_patty).

In the article the patty is described thus:

> ... contains various fillings and spices baked inside a flaky shell,
>   often tinted golden yellow with an egg yolk mixture or turmeric. It is
>   made like a turnover but is more savoury.

[image]

In Italy this type of stodgy finger food is virtually non-existent and has never really caught on in fashion. However, if an Italian had to describe the OP's snack food, they might describe it as being [vol-au-vents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vol-au-vent).  **Vol-au-vents** are always made from puff pastry, the small, golden-coloured shell cases are usually filled with a creamy savoury filling.

[image]

However, in the UK, as Barrie England pointed out, they would be recognized simply as **sausage rolls**, i.e., puff, flaky or short crust pastry, filled with sausage meat, rolled and baked in the oven. The most popular rolls are in fact made with sausages, but there are many variations on this theme, and not all of them need to be savoury. Due to their bite-sized portions they'll often be called **mini-sausage rolls**.

[image: mini sausage rolls]

Comparing the photos of the mini-sausage rolls with that of the OP's it seems pretty clear to me that the two snack foods share many similarities.

If one wanted to impress their guests with a fancy sounding name, I'd opt for vol-au-vent and call the mouthwatering dish, **Beef and mushroom vol-au-vents.** Otherwise, if your guests are unfamiliar with the term *Paszteciki*, I would suggest the more British sounding **Spicy beef mushroom rolls**

Comment: The best answer or comment so far. I've had many *pasties* in my life and what SF. posted is nothing like them. Your first photo shows what a proper pasty should look like.

Comment: The crust is supposed to be on the side because that is where a pasty is supposed to be held, while eating it.

Comment: Thank you @Tristan, I agree the photo SF posted look like sausage rolls, albeit the filling is quite different, so I suppose "Polish beef/pork/chicken rolls" would be a more descriptive choice.

Answer (score 3):

They look like **sausage rolls**, which traditionally contain, well, sausages. They could also be **spring rolls**, a supposedly Chinese preparation. If you wanted to be precise, I suppose you could call them **meat, mushroom and spice rolls**.

Comment: I've never encountered 'sausage rolls' in the US; we call the miniature ones with cocktail sausages 'pigs in blankets'.

Comment: Hm, that looks like pastry dough like you use for croissants.  And we do have *sausage rolls* in the US, @StoneyB.

Comment: In the UK, pigs in blankets, are small sausages wrapped with bacon strips and roasted in the oven. They don't have any pastry.

Answer (score 1):

English cuisine doesn't have anything quite like this, so unsurprisingly, there's no directly equivalent term. Your choices in such a case are (1) use the native term and hope it catches on (like, say, *pierogis* have), or (2) find the closest equivalent in English cuisine, and use that term, possibly with an ethnic marker. For the latter option, *[pasty](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pasty#Noun_2)* (or *pastie*) or *Polish pasty* is probably your best bet, since it's the only word I know that implies a savory filling. (In contrast, both *pie* and *pastry* tend to imply a sweet filling.)

Just be careful, because no matter how you spell it, *pasty* can have [an entirely different meaning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pasty#Noun). Make it clear that you're talking about food before you use this term.

Answer (score 1):

[Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_rn=4&gs_ri=psy-ab&cp=18&gs_id=b&xhr=t&q=paszteciki+pasties&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=paszteciki+pasties&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.Yms&fp=ce5d43a4985ebd88&biw=1280&bih=789) suggests that "paszteciki" are a kind of "pasties", but [bytebuster](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3053/232) found "puff patties". Both look very similar: the words "pasties" and "patties" as well as the photos of the meals. Being neither Polish nor English native speaker, I have to admit that I cannot decide which it is. (Maybe even both are used depending on details of the recipe?)